# Firefox add-on for running multi-versions of FF

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, firefox-extensions

I found this add-on called [FoxTester](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/foxtester/) that lets you:

```
Install and launch multiple versions of Firefox, Fennec, Seamonkey and 
Thunderbird while using the default installations and without affecting 
the default user profiles.
```

Yet it is only avalaible for Linux. Is there a Windows (XP) equivalent to that add-on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ProfileManager is a tool that has been created by some Mozilla developers.

It displays the available profiles on startup with options to edit, copy, create, backup and delete profiles easily.

The profile manager can handle multiple Firefox versions on the system with an option to assign profiles to different versions of the browser.

You can find it at the [Mozilla ftp server](ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/utilities/profilemanager/)